# Exception Handling Reactive

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

**How does one use a `Mono.error(<Throwable>)` but attach information from the body returned from a request?**

- Is there a reactive object that extends `Throwable` that takes a Mono/Flux object, so the error being thrown will wait for the body to be accounted for?
- Or is there a way to add some sort of 'flag' onto an existing Mono object to make it fail instantly (to circumvent the requirement to be `Throwable`)

Example scenario below:

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

private someMethod() {
    webClient.get().retrieve().onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, this::errorHandler)
}
```

---

```
private Mono<? extends Throwable> errorHandler(ClientResponse cr) {
    Mono<String> body = cr.body(BodyExtractors.toMono(String.class));

        ...<do something here>...

    return Mono.error(new WhateverException());
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return body.flatMap(str -> Mono.error(new WhateverException(str)));
```